# Need Swipe tab bar position but not in the action bar

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I am trying to implement the tabs somewhere in the screen but not at the top as displayed in the screenshot.

[image]

I tried action bar tabs but these tabs always attached to action bar i.e at the top of screen. How can i use TABS below the image as shown the screenshot.

Thanks

Comment: post xml file where you created tabs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

[PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

or if you want to have a google one you can try:

[PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html)

the implementation of the first one is straight forward and explained in the link for the second one copy the java files from view folder and add them to your project and the rest of the work is similar to the first one.

in xml:

```
    <com.example.android.common.view.SlidingTabLayout
          android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and then you can use `ViewPager` to change the views.